# Windows hotkeys not working?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Can we use the usual Microsoft keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu? The proverbial <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> work correctly, but the other keys don't.

For example, open Explorer, minimize all Windows. Not every Ubuntu distribution can lock the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> screen. It would be incredibly useful if someone knew any application, or other idea, to do such things.

It's very important for blind man, who use Linux. It's very important also for remote Virtual PC, and some special soft.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts vary on desktop (thus flavor), and in some cases by release (different versions of desktop occur in different releases, and desktop can change between releases in rare circumstance).  You didn't mention OS/release or flavor (desktop)

Comment: Include information that is essential to answer the question in your question, i.e. edit your question to include information on your desktop.

Comment: By the way, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are not “Microsoft keyboard shortcuts”, they [originated at Xerox PARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C#In_graphical_environments). The Microsft keyboard shortcuts to copy-paste are Ctrl-Ins and Shift-Ins.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings* -> *Device* -> *Keyboard*

Here you can view existing keyboard shortcuts and create custom ones.

If you want to see/modify which shortcut are already used (like lock screen), you would be able to watch a list, or you can scroll down until you see a <kbd>+</kbd> icon which allow you to create a custom shortcut.

Personally, I have a shortcut to open *System Monitor* (that's not a default package, use `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` to install it) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is already used for disconnection), but you can do whatever you like. So just add the `gnome-system-monitor` command inside the command field when you create the shortcut.

Note: <kbd>Win</kbd> is called <kbd>Super</kbd> in the Linux language.