# How to make most of Ubuntu shortcut-keys as in Windows

Tags: shortcut-keys

is there a method to make Ubuntu 20+ (GUI) using hotkeys (CTR+F , ALT-TAB, WinKey) as close as possible to Windows OS ?
As still as I understand one needs to manually change setting for each key wich is quite a task. Maybe there is a way to set them all (or most of them)?

Comment: there is an [existing question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189730/windows-hotkeys-not-working) asking exactly this, but no application to set them for you is suggested, just the manual method.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts are a personal preference. The operating system comes with defaults, but you can change them.

Indeed, you need to define keyboard shortcuts one by one. However, there are ways to store these changes and implement them automatically on a new or different installation. How that works, depends on the desktop environment you are using.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/217310/558158) provides a script that automatically can export and import custom shortcut keys on the Ubuntu desktop. Shortcuts set in different other locations can be set with `gsettings set...`, so also this can be scripted for automation.